# bootstrap-fullscreen-select not working when placed in form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, fullscreen

**>hi this multiselect code is working fine but when it is placed in a form it stop working,please help me! when it is place in form is does not load at all**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>


    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="bootstrap-fullscreen-select.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-fullscreen-select.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>
<body>



    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="food" >Country</label>
    <select id="food" class="form-control mobileSelect " multiple data-style="warning" >
        <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
        <option value="burger">Burger</option>
        <option value="tacos">Tacos</option>
        <option value="garlic-bread">Garlic Bread</option>

        <script>$('.mobileSelect').mobileSelect(

                {   animation: 'top',
                    animationSpeed: 400}
        );
        </script>
    </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: custom css perhaps?

Comment: There is no additional css

Comment: can you reproduce it? (make it work) cause for me it won't work at all what you are trying in bootply: http://www.bootply.com/0xZtVhGHfV

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: this also should be added to the header but I can't find the online library, it must be downloaded :

Comment: https://github.com/craftpip/bootstrap-fullscreen-select/tree/master/dist and placed in the header as  <script src="bootstrap-fullscreen-select.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-fullscreen-select.css">